# Setting email priority using mailto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, mailto

Is there a way to set the priority of an email using mailto? Or any alternatives (javascript, jQuery) that could set the priority?

At the moment I am creating emails using mailto to set the subject, body, recipient etc. But I can't figure out any way to set the priority from the mailto link(I am using outlook 2007).

I would be willing to to switch to something other than mailto if it means I can set the priority.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes in theory. The [mailto specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) accepts [header keys and values](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_471.asp) so this might do the trick...

`mailto:test@test.com?subject=test&X-Priority=1&X-MSMail-Priority=High&Importance=High`

However mail clients behave very differently. Don't expect every client to support it. It failed my testing on OSX with Mail (which itself sets X-Priority:1 when I do it from within the client). Does it work for Outlook 2007?

Crafting mail headers might be better done with command line tools or a scripting language.

Comment: That didn't work for me, I guess outlook 2007 doesn't support it either, thanks for your help though, I'll try and look into some alternatives